# Find the language of a given grammar

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammar

I have the following grammar:

S ⇒ Aa

A ⇒ B

B ⇒ Aa

I need to find the language of this grammar but I am having trouble. I have never had to make a language out of a grammar that has no end state so I am not sure how to approach it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language generated by a grammar is defined to be the set of all strings of terminals that can be derived from the grammar. Since you can't derive any strings of terminals from your grammar, the language is empty.